# Backgroung color toolbar and menubar in windows 7

Tags: c++, winapi, mfc

I want to change the backgroung color of the toolbar and the menu bar of my application in Windows 7.

I have this look:

[image]

but I want this look:

[image]

So I'd like to know - this problem is connected with Visual Styles, and can be solved with some functions / changes of color scheme of application or I should write my own classes and set the particular color in RGBenter image description here.

If you have any example code, I would glad to see it.

Comment: Yes, it is a visual styles thing. When visual styles are enabled, that's how Windows draws menu bars and toolbars. Look at any Windows application and you'll see that they are blue-ish. Why do you want your application to look different?

Answer (score 1):

As Cody indicated, you need to use visual styles.  When you create a new project in Visual Studio, you’re given the opportunity to specify a visual style.

[image]

The new application uses the [CMFCVisualManager](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb984129(v=vs.120).aspx) class to render the individual UI components.

CMFCVisualManager...

> Provides support for changing the appearance of your application at a
>   global level. The CMFCVisualManager class works together with a class
>   that provides instructions to draw the GUI controls of your
>   application using a consistent style.

If you’re dealing with an existing application, you would need to add the VisualManager class to your code.  I would suggest you create a sample application and look at the code that gets generated.  Once you understand how the code works, you can port what you need to your application.

Comment: This actually isn't visual styles. At least, it's not the *real* visual styles as defined by the operating system, which apply to the common controls. Rather, it is a series of custom themes provided by the MFC expansion pack. Coincidence that they used the same name. These are all owner-drawn by the library code, not the operating system.

Comment: Thank you. I've just found the sample in Visual Studio which demonstate the work of CMFCVisualManager - MFCTaskbar. But now I'd like to know - only installed visual styles are existed - I mean : VS2008(2005), OfficeXP(2003,2005) etc or I can find anywhere another additional styles?

Comment: Particulary, I have such problem: When I choose CMFCVisualManagerWindows, I recieve  the same style like CMFCVisualManagerWindows7. If I change the Windows theme to WindowsXp, than I recieve what I probaply want to see. However, when I choose CMFCVisualManagerOfficeXP, I always get the same window(in XP theme, in Windows7 theme). 
So questions are : How can I recieve WindowsXP style in Windows7? How can I change the background color in CMFCVisualManagerWindows7 like in CMFCVisualManagerOfficeXP?

Comment: @DmitryLazdin You should take a look at the many event handlers provided by that class and its base class.  They provide the opportunity to customize the rendering of many GUI objects.

Comment: @mirower Can you give me, please, example, how can I change the background color of toolbar?